# Override overflow:hidden in browser

Tags: html, css, overflow

Some websites currently break functionality by placing overflow:hidden style into html and body tags to bully users into having lots of unwanted garbage displayed. As a user, how can i best override that?

Only talking about those two tags, where a site controlling overflow is nearly always doing so maliciously.

Answer (score 0):

you could alter that from your browser's dev tools like inspect

Comment: yes, but doing that every time after loading the page is tedious

Answer (score 0):

You can use Devtools or try make or Found some plugin who change the overflow:hidden in browser or you can use Python i think.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting an `overflow-y: visible !important;` in the `body` & `html` tags, that's to keep the y-axis with a scrolling functionality.

And if you don't want scrolling sideways on phones and tablets then add as well `overflow-x: hidden;` to both the `body` & `html` tags alonside with a `position: relative;` for the `body` tag, too

Comment: it is not about pages i have control of, but ones i load as a user

Comment: In that case not so sure